# Volumetric Fog Shader - Camera Issue

Tags: directx, unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

I am trying to build an infinite fog shader. This fog is applied on a 3D plane.
For the moment I have a Z-Depth Fog. And I encounter some issues.
As you can see in the screenshot, there are two views.
The green color is my 3D plane. The problem is in the red line. It seems that the this line depends of my camera which is not good because when I rotate my camera the line is affected by my camera position and rotation.

[image]

I don't know where does it comes from and how to have my fog limit not based on the camera position.

**Shader**

```
Pass {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform float4      _FogColor;
            uniform sampler2D   _CameraDepthTexture;
            float               _Depth;
            float               _DepthScale;

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 projection : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 screenPosition : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

            // o.projection = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.pos);
        float4 position = o.pos;
        #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
        float scale = -1.0;
        #else
        float scale = 1.0;
        #endif
        float4 p = position * 0.5f;
        p.xy = float2(p.x, p.y * scale) + p.w;
        p.zw = position.zw;
        o.projection = p;

                // o.screenPosition = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
        position = o.pos;
        float4 q = position * 0.5f;
        #if defined(UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET)
        q.xy = float2(q.x, q.y * _ProjectionParams.x) + q.w * _ScreenParams.zw;
        #else
        q.xy = float2(q.x, q.y * _ProjectionParams.x) + q.w;
        #endif
        #if defined(SHADER_API_FLASH)
        q.xy *= unity_NPOTScale.xy;
        #endif
            q.zw = position.zw;
        q.zw = 1.0f;
        o.screenPosition = q;

                return o;
            }
            sampler2D _GrabTexture;

            float4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR {
                float3 uv = UNITY_PROJ_COORD(IN.projection);
                float depth = UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, uv));
                depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
                return saturate((depth - IN.screenPosition.w + _Depth) * _DepthScale);
            }
        ENDCG
    }
```

Next I want to rotate my Fog to have an Y-Depth Fog but I don't know how to achieve this effect.

Comment: But fog depends on camera position by nature unless you have some definitive fog geometry, and even in that case it have to depend on camera, but also be affected by its geometry.

Comment: Of course it has to depend of the camera position. But the screenshot below shows an effect that doesn't fit with my needs. I updated the shader's code with the content of ComputeGrabScreenPos and ComputeScreenPos.

Comment: Then I do not quite understand what you are trying to acheive and what is your problem exactly can you elaborate?

Comment: If you look at my answer and the screenshot with the blue line I think you will understand my problem. What you see in black is the actual behaviour which is for me "false". And the blue line is that what it should be. A fog parallel with my plane not my camera (the first sreenshots shows the problem I think). The fog should be base on the plane orientation. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: So your fog starts at the plane and does not exists before it and when you look to the object before the plane you want them as if there is no fog?

Comment: My 3D plane is like a windows. When you look threw it, you will see the objects fogged with an infinite fog. I think that's what you sayed if I understood you well.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to acheive what you want:

1. is to render depth of your plane to texture and calculate fog based on difference of depth of plane and depth of object, 0 if obj depth is less and (objDepth - planeDepth) * scale if it is bigger)
2. Is to instead of rendering to texture calculate distance to plane in shader and use it directly.

I am not sure what you do since I am not very familiar with Unity surface shaders, but djudging from the code and result something different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is caused by _CameraDepthTexture, that's why depth is calculated with the camera position.
But I don't know how to correct it... It seems that there is no way to get the depth from another point. Any idea ?

Here is another example. In green You can "see" the object and the blue line is for me the fog as it should be.

[image]