# Project camera depth onto a 3D plane

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, cg

Is it possible to project the camera depth onto a plane ?
Let me explain, if I simply transfer the depth buffer on a plane, it will always display the depth from the camera point of view. But how can I proceed to display the depth but from the plane point of view.
I want to apply the effect on a shader. For me it's maybe a matrix problematic but I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

The depth buffer is relative to the representation, it is possible to project it to any plane using (for example) shaders. But..

The depth buffer is not a full geometrical representation of the object, but only of the "being seen" surface from the camara POV.
If you project the depth buffer, part of the object will probably not be projected (see image).

*In the picture, the camara (the red eye) is looking to an object (black). The depth buffer represent the distance between the camara and the red surface.
For the plane (blue line) you probably want to get the entire object projection (blue surface), but projecting the red surface on the plane, you will only get a little portion of the entire blue surface.*

[image: Projection depth buffer]

If you want the entire blue surface,

1. Change the POV of the camara to just behind the plane.
2. Render the scene.
3. Get your depth buffer and save it into a texture/image/buffer (P).
4. Reset your camara POV
5. Render the scene with using for your shader the image (P)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, of course the depth buffer is not a geometrical representation of the object. In my example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123558/volumetric-fog-shader-camera-issue/17163017#17163017), I have the point of view of the camera and I don't know how to have the POV of the plane. Do you understand the problem ? I don't know how to proceed to have the correct depth.

Comment: Supposing that your plane is a QUAD(A,B,C,D), 

1) Using the cross product of A-B and A-C, you get the normal of the plane. This may be used as camara direction.

2) You may use the central point of the quad as the camara position: (A+C)/2.

3) Set the camara to ortogonal and others parameters depending on what you want. This is probably what is "dificult".
Eg. The dimension of the "far" plane of the camara may be the size of your QUAD

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer, I was wondering if a new camera was necessary but it seems that it is... I thought that if I played with some matrix in the shader to change the point of view of the position it would work.